Is it ethical/acceptable to recommend a reviewer who gave a positive review to a previous submission of the same MS?
I (and my co-authors) recently received a rejection notice regarding a manuscript we submitted for publication. We had one positive and one negative review. The positive reviewer chose to reveal his identity; however, the negative reviewer remains anonymous.
We plan to submit a revised version, following both reviewers' feedback, to another journal. Is it acceptable/ethical to recommend the reviewer who provided us with a positive review as a reviewer for the revised MS? If so, do we need to 1) reach out and ask him first and 2) reveal the situation to the journal's editor?

Yes, recommending the same reviewer is an acceptable recommendation, especially if their feedback was constructive and insightful in a way that helped improving the manuscript. At the end of the day, it's the editor decision to send them the manuscript or not. Therefore,
2-) Is necessary. Providing this information to the editor is a must to give them a complete understanding of the manuscript revision, and to allow them to make an informed decision about which reviewers they will send the MS to.
1-) Is unnecessary and can be awkward.

There is no guarantee the editor will send them the manuscript,
and if so, it's an editorial job to ask about their willingness to
review it again. Within the same journal, reviewers are usually asked
if they are willing to review a revised version of the MS when they
submit their feedback. In this case, the reviewer revealing their
identity can be at least a sign that they are open to be reached out
again about their feedback.
From a reviewer perspective who revealed their identity, receiving
the MS again from a different journal should tell the whole story:
the MS was rejected in journal 1, revised and resubmitted to journal
2. Knowing whether they were recommended by the editor or the author is irrelevant.


Avoid "cherry-picking" reviewers and be open with the new journal editor
Using the same referees across multiple submissions has the benefit of avoiding duplication of review tasks, so it has at least some desirable properties.  The drawback occurs when authors "cherry pick" only reviewers who previously gave positive feeback, which has the potential to bias academic publication decisions.
It is acceptable to recommend the previous positive reviewer as a reviewer for a new submission, but you should also strongly consider recommending the previous negative reviewer as well.  (After all, are you not confident in your revisions since that reviewer previously read your paper?)  It is also desirable to explain the full situation to the editor of the new journal so that they are aware of the reviewers' previous exposure to your paper and previous recommendations on your paper.  As long as you are open about the history of your paper, this will be ethical action and it will ensure that your actions do not bias the review process.

I feel confident we have addressed the issues highlighted in the negative review; however, the reviewer remained anonymous. Therefore, we are unable to recommend them as a reviewer during the future submission. That said, I have no problem being transparent with the future editor. Do you think I should share the full reviews with the next editor, during submission of the manuscript? Or will a summary of the key points addressed suffice?

Ah, good point (sorry I missed that).  I think it would be fine to let the editor of the new journal know that you can provide the previous reviews if those are helpful.  Since you have addressed the old review points, the editor might decide that fresh reviews are more helpful.

Yes, but 2) is necessary. It is unusual for a reviewer to have revealed their identity, so the editor will not guess that you know they previously gave a good review, and it would be dishonest to take advantage of that.
And 1) would be a good thing to do too. The reviewer might not guess that you are going to recommend them in this way. It is better to be open and honest.
